# WPF - Keyboard Focus Doesn't Overlay Control

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

The screenshot below shows my problem. I have an `ItemsControl` where the `DataTemplate` for the items contains a `CheckBox` and a `TextBox` followed by some text. When I tab from a `TextBox` onto the `CheckBox` on the next row, it correctly receives the keyboard focus, but the little visual focus rectangle is in the wrong spot - always in the top left corner of the `ItemsControl` regardless of which item has the focus. What? I added a trigger to highlight `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` with green to show that the focus is in the correct place. Pressing `Spacebar` unchecks the green checkbox.

[image: Keyboard visual focus doesn't overlay control]

Changing the value in the `TextBox` does result in recomputing some stuff in another window. There is a slight lag (< 1 sec at least on this machine) and If I close the window that reacts to the value change, the problem goes away. Is it possible that the visual focus can be drawn before the layout of the visual tree used by the keyboard focus has finished updating?

I'm not terribly concerned about fixing this problem. I'd just like to know if there's any reason why this makes sense?

Comment: Could you please post the minimal example reproducing the problem?

Comment: @Vlad Not really sure how it could be reproduced - it depends on a fair amount of work happening when the property behind the TextBox is set, I obviously can't post my entire computation. I'll strip it down though and see if I can get it to happen with some sort of faked delay.